# How to sort keys from a text file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have a text file that contains numbers like this in a text file:

```
7.2: 2
7.3: 2
6.5: 2
6.4: 6
6.3: 2
7.7: 2
6.1: 3
7.5: 1
7.8: 4
7.9: 1
6.9: 3
6.8: 4
10.1: 8
10.0: 9
10.3: 7
10.2: 10
10.5: 13
10.4: 18
10.7: 8
```

What I want is to sort them using the keys only. I can't append them in a dictionary and sort it using the keys only. This is what I've tried.

```
def sorting():
    file = open(r'test.txt', 'r')
    text = file.read().split()
    keys = {}
    for num in text:
        if num not in keys:
            keys.append(num)
            keys.sort(key=float)
    json.dump(keys, open('test1.txt', 'r')

sorting()
```

Comment: @ShadowRanger thank you, I edited my question. and put the code that didn't work for me.

Comment: That newly code isn't syntactically valid (missing parens), and has serious basic errors (writing to file opened read-only). Try simplifying your function to doing one thing (say, sorting lines read from such a file and returning them, no I/O from and to files). Playing around with the more targeted code in the interactive interpreter might help you understand the sorting step. Simple `print`s (e.g. `print text[0]`) might help you understand the issues with I/O (hint: Your keys and values are not even being stored together in the same index of the `list`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you! I understand it now. That hint helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the lines, split them on the colon to tuples, sort them using the second value, and then write them to the output file.

Sample code:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as in_file:
  lines = sorted((l.split(": ") for l in in_file.readlines()), key=lambda l: float(l[0]))
  with open('output.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for line in lines:
       out_file.write(": ".join(line))
```

Comment: Good catch! Fixed.

Comment: @HeshamAttia THANK YOU SO MUCH! It works! Although I changed the `double` into `float`, because there's an error saying: `NameError: global name 'double' is not defined`. But this helps me!! Thanks a lot!